How can I save a figure to PDF with a specific page size and padding?
I have generated a matplotlib figure that I want to save to a PDF. So far, this is straightforward.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [3, 5, 4, 7]
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.savefig(
    "example.pdf",
    bbox_inches = "tight"
)
plt.close()

However, I would like the figure to appear in the middle of a standard page and have some white space around the figure, rather than fill up the entire page. How can I tweak the above to achieve this?

@gre_gor No, that is not the same, as it does not address saving to a PDF format and adjusting the figure to be smaller than the full page.

Another option is to use constrained layout and set a rectangle that you want the all the plot elements to be contained in.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [3, 5, 4, 7]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8.3, 11.7), layout='constrained')
fig.get_layout_engine().set(rect=(0.15, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4))  # left, bottom, width, height in fractions of the figure

ax.scatter(x, y)

fig.savefig('example.pdf')

plt.close()



Save as PostScript and convert to PDF
One possible way is saving the figure as a PostScript image and then converting it to PDF. This approach provides additional parameters such as orientation ('landscape' or 'portrait') and papertype ('letter', 'legal', 'executive', 'ledger', 'a0' through 'a10', 'b0' through 'b10'). See the pyplot.savefig documentation for details.
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [3, 5, 4, 7]
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.savefig("example.ps",      # note the .ps extension in the file name
            bbox_inches = "tight",    
            orientation = "portrait", 
            papertype = "a4")
plt.close()

As for converting, we can use the ps2pdf utility from Ghostscript package:
ps2pdf example.ps example.pdf


Tweak the figure size and place custom axes
Another alternative is working with a custom axis, while the figure is set to the required page size:
# Define the page and plot size
inch = lambda mm: mm/25.4                         # convert millimeters to inches
page_width, page_height = map(inch, [210, 297])   # set page of size 210mm×297mm
plot_width, plot_height = map(inch, [100, 80])    # set plot of size 100mm×80mm

# Calculate axis parameters relative to the page size: 
# rect=(left, bottom, width, height)
left_pad, bottom_pad = (page_width - plot_width)/2, (page_height - plot_height)/2
rect = (left_pad/page_width, bottom_pad/page_height,        
        plot_width/page_width, plot_height/page_height)      

# Tweak the figure size to fit the page 
# and place a custom-sized axis to draw plots
fig = plt.figure(dpi = 300, figsize = (page_width, page_height))
ax = fig.add_axes(rect)            

ax.scatter([1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 4, 7])             
fig.savefig("example2.pdf")
plt.close()

See Introduction to Axes for further details.
Tweak the figure size and slice it into subfigures
To have more flexibility with axes, we can divide the figure into subfigures and use the central one for plotting. For example, we slice the main figure into 9 parts (3×3). The central part is used to draw two plots, while the others provide padding. To visualize the different subfigures, they are filled with contrasting colors.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import chain, islice

inch = lambda mm: mm/25.4                         # convert millimeters to inches
page_width, page_height = map(inch, [210, 297])   # set page of size 210mm×297mm
plot_width, plot_height = map(inch, [100, 80])    # set plot of size 100mm×80mm
vertical_pad = (page_height - plot_height)/2      # top and bottom space
horizontal_pad = (page_width - plot_width)/2      # left and right space

fig = plt.figure(dpi = 300, figsize = (page_width, page_height))
sub_figs = fig.subfigures(nrows=3, ncols=3, 
                         width_ratios=[horizontal_pad, plot_width, horizontal_pad],
                         height_ratios=[vertical_pad, plot_height, vertical_pad])
for f in islice(chain(*sub_figs), 1, None, 2):
    f.set_facecolor('GreenYellow')
plot_fig = sub_figs[1, 1]          # The central figure where plots are drawn
plot_fig.set_facecolor('YellowGreen')
ax1, ax2 = plot_fig.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True,
                             width_ratios=[1, 6])
ax1.boxplot(y:=[3, 5, 4, 7, 8, 7, 5, 5, 7, 3, 3, 5, 1, 2])
ax2.plot(y)
fig.savefig("example3.pdf", metadata={'Title': 'Sliced Figure'})
plt.close()


See Figure.subfigures for details.

You can use the matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages module. Here's the code for it:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [3, 5, 4, 7]

# Creating the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)

page_width, page_height = 8.3, 11.7   # A4 size in inches 

with PdfPages("example_with_whitespace.pdf") as pdf:
    fig.set_size_inches(page_width, page_height)
    #Center the figure by using `tight_layout`
    pdf.savefig(fig, bbox_inches="tight", dpi=300, pad_inches=2.0)

Use fig.set_size_inches(width, height) to control the size of the figure. And pad_inches helps to add whitespace around the figure.
This approach will ensure your figure is centered with whitespace around it on a standard-sized PDF page.

PdfPages is the right thing to use if you want multiple pages in your pdf.  However, if you want the specific height and width that you set, you should not use bbox_inches="tight", as that resizes the figure.
